# How do I store the result of a function in a variable if I'm timing how long it takes using timeit?

Tags: python, timeit

I have to time how long it takes a function to run that returns a list. I want to store the time it takes it to run in a variable, and store the list the function returns. How do I go about storing both?

Example that returns the time but loses the result:

```
t1 = timeit.timeit(myFunction())
```

If myFunction returns a list, how do I store it and the time? Is this possible?

Comment: `timeit` is a tool that is supposed to be run in testing and debugging situations on small isolated parts of the code. It is not meant to run inside your normal runs. So, when used as intended there is no need to store the result. If you want to trace calls within the normal execusion you might be happier with the trace module, a simple `time.time()` based decorator, or tools like Zipkin (depending on your requirements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the "old fashion way":

```
start = time.time()
var = myFunction()
end = time.time()
time_needed = end - start
print(var, time_needed)
```

Comment: I should have explored more options than timeit. Thank you sir.